# How can you perform the IsRegExp operation (ECMA-262 §7.2.8) from JS code

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

The JavaScript standard defines an "abstract operation" for deciding whether an arbitrary object should be treated as a regular expression object.  I'll quote the spec here:

> The abstract operation IsRegExp takes [one argument] argument and returns [a Boolean indicating whether the object should be treated as a regular expression]. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. If the argument is not an Object, return false.
> 2. Let *matcher* be ?[Get](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-o-p)(argument, @@match).
> 3. If *matcher* is not `undefined`, return [ToBoolean](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toboolean)(matcher).
> 4. If argument has a [[RegExpMatcher]] internal slot, return true.
> 5. Return false.
>
> — [ECMA-262 §7.2.8 IsRegExp](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isregexp)

This is, for instance, what `"haystack".search(needle)` does to decide whether `needle` should be processed as a regex.

As far as I can tell, there is no API exposed to JavaScript programs that *just* performs this abstract operation.  It's *almost* possible to translate it to open code, but I don't know how to do step 4:

```
function IsRegExp(x) {
  // step 1
  if (typeof x !== "object" || x === null)
    return false;

  // steps 2 and 3
  if (Symbol.match in x)
    return !!x[Symbol.match];

  // step 4
  ???

  // step 5
  return false;
}
```

So here's the actual question: *Is it possible to write ordinary JavaScript code that performs step 4?*  If so, what is that code?  Alternatively, have I missed some built-in way to do the entire IsRegExp operation, or some clever way to exploit the overall semantics of `String.prototype.search` to get the answer to "is this a regex", or something like that?

---

If you're wondering what one might need this for,

```
function ensureRegExp(x) {
  return IsRegExp(x) ? x : new RegExp(x, "u");
}
```

Comment: A regex is an object as you already know. You can try doing JSON.stringify the regex, it will have that opening and ending "/" with an optional flag at the end.

Comment: The spec describes how to *implement* Javascript, there is nothing that requires an operation to be exposed to the user except where it explicitly says so.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I know. The question is, is _this particular operation_ exposed (either the entire "IsRegExp" operation, or the troublesome step 4)? I am not aware of any way to do it, but I could easily have missed something.

Answer (score 4):

The only problem here is the

> If argument has a [[RegExpMatcher]] internal slot, return true.

It's not possible for JavaScript alone to check or access internal slots (without native code being provided that does so). For the same reason, if you do `someMap.set(key, value)`, it's impossible to retrieve either the `key` or the `value` from the Map unless you invoke one of the methods provided for such a thing, such as `Map.prototype.entries` or `Map.prototype.keys`, which invoke native code to look up the map keys/values in an internal slot.

So, that step with `[[RegExpMatcher]]` is impossible to replicate *exactly*.

That said, regular expressions are instances of `RegExp`, so 99% of the time, in sane code, a plain `instanceof` check will work.

```js
console.log(/foo/ instanceof RegExp);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(/foo/) === RegExp.prototype);
```